# Using TouchAFPosition with Sony a6500 Camera

Tags: camera, sony

I am trying to use setTouchAFPosition with Sony Camera Remote API version 2.40 and a a6500 Camera.

I am able to get the Liveview and actTakePicture to work but any time I call "setTouchAFPosition" I keep getting "Not Available Now".

Has anyone been able to use this function with the a6500 camera or similar?

Answer (score 0):

It could have something to do with the a6500 not supporting "Tracking Focus". Try running the "getSupportedCameraFunction" and "getAvailableCameraFunction" commands to see if the "setTouchAFPosition" commands is returned in the list.